# allure.attach changes file name

Tags: jenkins, allure, python-behave

When I save an attachment like this:

```
allure.attach(context.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="nameOfTheFile.png", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

It saves the file in allure/data/attachments as something like **e1fbefaf43e209d5.png**

I want it to keep the name given **nameOfTheFile.png** so I can attach them to an email. Since I am having trouble attaching the entire allure report via Jenkins I at least want named images.

**Question:** How can I use allure.attach without it changing the name of the files randomly.